# User-created function not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba, function

I want to create a function that checks to see cell A2 in worksheet 1 contains any of the values in a separate column.

Column 1 (sheet1)

- poor
- baby
- son

Column 1 (sheet4)

- poor
- rich
- baby
- adult
- daughter
- mother

I have the following code:

```
Function KeepActive(catchAll As String) As String

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 500
    If InStr(catchAll, Sheet4.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        catchAll = "match"
    Else
        catchAll = "no match"
    End If
Next i

KeepActive = catchAll

End Function
```

catchAll is referring to the respective cell in column 1.

So the code theoretically should be seeing if "poor" "baby" and "son" is present within column 2.

This should return two "match" and one "no match", but it's returning three "match".

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: It _looks_ like you might be using Excel?  You may want to add the [excel] and/or [excel-vba] tags to get more/relevant eyes on your question if that's the case.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. fixed!

Comment: You don't exit the loop when you find a match, so you set catchAll to "match" then loop again and it can be changed back to "no match", this will effectively only give you the result of the last checked value in the range. as others have suggested simply put an `Exit For` after you set `catchAll = "match"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Function KeepActive(catchAll As String) As String

Dim i As Long, rv as string

rv = "no match"
For i = 1 To 500
    If InStr(catchAll, Sheet4.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        rv = "match"
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

KeepActive = rv

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I believe this isn't working is you have no comparison try this. Other wise it will return 0 which is True.

```
KeepActive = "no match"
For i = 1 To 500
    If InStr(catchAll, Sheet4.Cells(i, 1).Value) > 0 Then
        KeepActive= "match"
        exit for 
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you modify `CatchAll` after the first cycle.  So you are comparing the string "Match" or "No Match" rather than the original argument.

Also, you need to exit the code after you find a match.

Or, you could just use the Range.Find method:

---

```
Option Explicit
Function KeepActive(catchAll As String) As String
  Dim C As Range

Set C = Sheet4.Columns(1).Find(what:=catchAll, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=False)

If Not C Is Nothing Then
    KeepActive = "Match"
Else
    KeepActive = "No Match"
End If

End Function
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this with an array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A1:A6,A1:A3)>0,1,0))
```

CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER after you enter the formula as opposed to just ENTER. It returns 2 for 2 matches.

Alternatively if you want a row by row formula just:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A$1:A$6,A1)>0,"Match","No Match")
```

then drag down